# how to test a parent call to a class wrapper

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following class I would like to cover with some tests:

```
namespace Nietonfir\RaygunBundle\Services;

use Raygun4php\RaygunClient;

class Client extends RaygunClient implements NietonfirRaygunClient
{
    private $defaultTags = null;

    protected function mergeTags($tags)
    {
        if (is_array($this->defaultTags)) {
            if (is_array($tags)) {
                $tags = array_merge($this->defaultTags, $tags);
            } else {
                $tags = $this->defaultTags;
            }
        }

        return $tags;
    }

    public function setDefaultTags(array $tags)
    {
        if (0 == count($tags)) {
            $this->defaultTags = null;
        }

        $this->defaultTags = $tags;
    }

    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        parent::SetVersion($version);
    }

    public function sendException($exception, $tags = null, $userCustomData = null, $timestamp = null)
    {
        $tags = $this->mergeTags($tags);
        parent::SendException($exception, $tags, $userCustomData, $timestamp);
    }

    public function sendError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $tags = null, $userCustomData = null, $timestamp = null)
    {
        $tags = $this->mergeTags($tags);
        return parent::SendError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $tags, $userCustomData, $timestamp);
    }
}
```

In specific I would like to test that `sendException` calls `parent::SendException` with the right `$tags` parameter. The problem of course is mocking the parent in some way, but I think it's hardly impossible. I was thinking of refactoring the class in order to make `Client` point to an instance of `RaygunClient` by means of an attribute. That way, it could be testable, but I'm not sure it's a nifty way to do that. After all, what I want is slightly changing the original parent class calls with normalized arguments.

Any piece of suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: *" I would like to test that `sendException` calls `parent::SendException` with the right $tags parameter."* -- you are about to write a brittle test. Test the effects of the method, not its implementation.

Comment: @axiac yeah, could be. But that method just tweaks a single parameter. The sole `parent::SendError` effect is sending an error through a `curl` exec command. I'm still thinking how properly test the expected behavior then

Comment: leaving aside the point of redesigning towards composition over inheritance, I think you system would definetly benefit from extracting all that `curl` stuff to a separate class.You will get all related things a lot more testable and DRY. You might event think of doing two -- one is a mere wrapper over php `curl` functions and another one is smth more adopted for the specific needs of your client classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as a comment, but it works as an answer and possible solution for you.

You clarified in the comments that the method you want to be called in your test case will send a cURL request. You want to avoid *actually* sending that request out during your test, since what you are testing is not PHP's cURL library. If your cURL call is within that method you should probably extract it to another class.

You will then be able to mock *that* class in your test, inject it in to your *actual* system that you are trying to test, and assert that when that method is called to send the cURL request the parameters in the request match what you should expect in your test case. It shouldn't matter to your test *how* those parameters show up the way that they do, but I am assuming that they will be different in some detectable ('assertable') way when funnelled through your parent class' method.

Changes to your system down the road that break this functionality (by supplying the wrong parameters to the cURL request) would then be detected.